# ModuleNotFoundError with Python

Tags: import, module, biopython

I have installed Python using the .exe in C:\Python36. I use Anaconda Distribution and I have installed it using the .exe in C:\Anaconda3. I have installed biopython using the following prompt commands:

```
cd Python36 (to go into Python36 directory)
cd Scripts (to go into Scripts directory)
pip install C:\Users\Vaio\Desktop\biopython-1.68-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

I have a Python script named biology.py that import the biopython package like this:

```
import Bio
```

if I compile:

```
python biology.py
```

I got the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "biology.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Bio
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two Python distribution then? I don't know if it is necessary for you. Anaconda probably overwritten your Python path. Check for anaconda distribution and for Python36 distribution where the biopython was installed. You have probably installed the package for one distribution and running the other. Check what 'python' command is related to, and to which distribution pip installs new packages.

For anaconda you can install packages using

```
conda install -c anaconda biopython=1.68
```

You can see this post for managing multiple python distribution on windows here: [How can I control which Python distribution to pip install a package to when I have Python 2, Python 3, and Anaconda on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363813/how-can-i-control-which-python-distribution-to-pip-install-a-package-to-when-i-h)

Another thing, You can always install up-to-date version of biopython using just:

```
pip install biopython
```